# Debugging issue: My code changes are not happening

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I am hoping that someone can point me in the right direction to a frustrating issue I have encountered, please be gentle I am new to all this.

I am trying to debug some xml that my app uses to display on my android phone. It worked perfectly on my old phone, but since getting my new phone I need to play about with the layout.

Whatever I do to alter the layout, no change occurs when I debug the app on my device - it does not change. I have even commented out and EditText within the XML code, and it still appears as if it wasn't commented.

I have uninstall and debugged - no difference.

I have updated the version number in the manifest - no difference.

Can someone shed any light why my app is not reflecting the code changes?

Not sure what other relevant information cold help my question. If you need anything please ask.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: are you making changes to XML in right layout folder? Is it visible fine in XML Editor in eclipse?

Comment: I think I am - the change takes place in the graphical layout on eclipse, just not on my phone itself.

Comment: Clean your project. You'll probably fall in a worse situation, where R doesn't even build (and a lot of **red markers** will come out). This is OK, it just means that AT LEAST ONE of your XML files has some bug(s).

Comment: I do now have a LOT of RED in my activities - so this means? that my XML is bugged and that is why it wasn't updating?

Comment: @CornishDibley: Yes, that's it. Now **you need A TON OF PATIENCE**. And double check your xmls one by one. Even strings.xml, dimens.xml (but probably it's some layout file).

Comment: @Kanak Sony: well, thank you. It happened to me before, and I was really going insane... ;)

Comment: Me too have experienced it in early days :)

Comment: Thanks for the head up in  the right direction, and I will need a TON of patience, I have 23 layout files! are yellow warnings oneclipse acceptable?? I have already removed lots of 'xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"' as underlined in red ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the heads up earlier, they certainly put me on the right track to solving my problem.

The biggest help was updating my android SDK Build Tools, as this then highlighted all the XML syntax errors, and allowed me to work through them!

I now have a worked R.java and can finally see my code working on my phone!